# How to handle QML application shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I need to persist the state of a QML application when it shuts down, and to read it when the application loads.

I tried using `Component.onCompleted` and `Component.onDestruction` inside the `MainView`'s `Page`.

While this works fine on the desktop, on the device it doesn't: `Component.onDestruction` doesn't get called when you close the app.

What's the proper way of handling the application lifecycle?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu components include the [StateSaver](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04/Ubuntu.Components.StateSaver/) capability.  This allows QML properties to be saved at program exit and restored at restart.  For each element with properties you wish to save, set the `StateSaver.properties` property to a comma separated list of the properties that should be saved.

However, there are two enormous limitations of the StateSaver.  First, state will not be restored if you program is launched through the Uri handler.  Second, no state will be saved when your program is "closed properly".  I have no idea what counts as closing properly, and therefore I don't know how to test this.

As I was trying this out, I stumbled on something strange: If you set a StateSaver property on an element, Component.onDestruction gets called.  When I added to the main `Page` of a test app,

```
StateSaver.properties: "title"
StateSaver.enabled: false
```

my destruction handlers started getting called, at least on normal exits.  You may be able to combine this with the StateSaver to ensure state gets saved on both normal and abnormal exits.  I don't know that you can count of this behavior, though.  I suspect it may be an accident of the StateSaver implementation.

Another approach would be to save state every time something changes.  This ensures you don't have to do anything on exit; your state is already safe.  One problem with this approach is that state changes are often associated with changes in the app itself, and the saving process could induce sluggishness.  I ran into this sort of problem, so I [delayed the database write by one second](https://github.com/rschroll/beru/commit/4f2b317920df4f8030803b2b602ae007417dd6e5).  This is imperfect, since I would lose state if the program crashes during that second.  But I felt that the risk was small enough, and the change in state inconsequential enough, to make this acceptable.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that StateSaver was unreliable (at best). But even if it were reliable (and I sure hope it will be), it is not necessary convenient (for example for C++ classes).

Comment: For now I can save the state at each modification, but it is not a good solution since it makes the code awfully bloated (in addition to introducing sluggishness, and possibly battery drain).

Comment: Do you know if there is currently a bug report for this problem?

Comment: No idea.  I know little about StateSaver other than it exists.  It wasn't around when I started working on Beru, so I couldn't consider it then.  What I've heard about it since then does not inspire me to switch to it.